# How can I fix this error with querySelector is null?

Tags: javascript

> ```
> <form id="book-form">
>         <div class="form-group">
>        
>         <input type="submit" value="Add Book" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
>       </form>
> ```

> ```
> document.querySelector('#book-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
>   // Prevent actual submit
>   e.preventDefault();
>
>   // Get form values
>  
>
>
>   }
> });
> ```

> Every time I open the console, the Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null is shown up and the whole code didn't run properly.

Comment: Close your `div` tag.

Comment: Remove the last `}` of `addEventListener`.

Comment: Can you use getElementById() instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @ThisGuy That makes no difference here.

Comment: @Unmitigated, just a syntax error? not closed properly then?

Comment: You are probably running your script immediately, not on the `load` event or similar. The DOM will not have been populated yet.

Comment: Yes, the problem is about DOM wouldn't load properly, and by your guide and adding "defer"to end of my <script> like that <script src="main.js" defer></script> , the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code:

1. Close your `div` container.
2. Remove the second `}` of `addEventListener`.

```js
document.querySelector('#book-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    // Prevent actual submit
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get form values
    console.log("Worked");

});
```

```html
<form id="book-form">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Book" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

Comment: I had a mistake here and it's that I delete some part of code , Thank you all . I clear that the </div> deleted mistakely and {} contains other function which deleted by me.